# Create HTML Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create html multiple tab like below screenshot .
[image]

In my below code I have created tabs but not able to give same look like how to cut button like / and \ on top . Also line below tab button

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Filter')">Filter</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Algorithm')">Algorithm</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Settings')">Settings</button>
</div>

<div id="Filter" class="tabcontent" style="display:block">
  <h3>Filter</h3>
  <p>Filter is the capital</p>
</div>

<div id="Algorithm" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Algorithm</h3>
  <p>Algorithm</p> 
</div>

<div id="Settings" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Settings</h3>
  <p>Settings Tab Content</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPEELp), seems like it's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this with `clip-path` main issue is getting the borders, because `clip-path` doesn't support them, but we can make them with a small hack. Here is the example for you it should give you a nice start how to do this:

```css
.slanted {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 94% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 94% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.slanted:before {
  content: '';
  width: 198px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 94% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 94% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: red;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slanted"></div>
```

Comment: clip-path is not supported on all browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: you could try to make them with :before and :after pseudo-elements

Comment: Can you help me to do this

Comment: @Kathara Yes but it has decent support over 80% and It all depends on what OP requirements know.

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 I've created a pen for you to play around with: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/OOEEyR  you could probably play around with z-orders, left and right as well, this I have not included in my pen. But I hope you'll get the gist of it. :)